# Radio buttons floating on my firefox but not on my friends firefox

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

I'm using this CSS code to display several radio buttons on the same line:

```
#new .radioLine
{
 width: 400px;
 float: left;
}

#new .radio
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
}
```

.radioLine surrounds the .radio divs, for example:

```
<div id="new">
<div class="radioLine">
 <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="one">One</div>
 <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="two">Two</div>
 <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="three">Three</div>
</div>
</div>
```

On my firefox browser these all appear on the same line, however the same page on my friends computer, also under firefox, appear each on a separate line.

Comment: These selectors shouldn't work on your markup as it is: `#new .radioLine` and `#new .radio`.

Comment: Your question lacks important OS and Firefox version information.

Comment: FF auto updates, right? If the browser version isn't an issue, then it might be the cache.. do you have it enabled on the site?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they should clear browser's cache. Or just refresh the page several times.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes to the CSS rules, because the selectors you're using won't work on the markup provided (there's no element with ID `new` anywhere):

```
.radioLine
{
    width: 400px;
}

.radio
{
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Example (working on FF, IE and Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/RNEJZ/